# how to efficiently load a big array to GPU shared memory?

Tags: c, cuda, memory-access, gpu-shared-memory

I want to load a big array to GPU shared memory.
when I employ that just like bellow:

1. ```
   int index = threadidx.x;
   ```
2. ```
   shared unsigned char x[1000];
   ```
3. ```
   x[i] = array[i];
   ```

Then if we call a kernel code with 1000 threads and one block, for every thread a memory access will occur?

Is it possible to load this array by a single memory access and store it to shared memory?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can't be done with a single access.

Using threads in parallel to load shared memory, just as you have shown, is the fastest way.  Shared memory can *only* be loaded by memory operations performed by threads in CUDA kernels.  There are no API functions to load shared memory.

If you have an array that is larger than the number of threads in a threadblock, you can use a looping approach like the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419822/efficiently-initializing-shared-memory-array-in-cuda/24419969#24419969).

Comment: by this way, does loading array elements into shared memory happened at once and parallel?

Comment: The only "parallel" "at once" activity will be at the warp level.  Each warp (32 threads) will combine their accesses to global memory (`array[i]`) into a single access/transaction, and will combine their accesses to shared memory (`x[i]`) into a single access.  Multiple warps may also be executing in parallel, but their activity will not be combined into a single memory transaction.

Comment: You'll usually get better load/store efficiency by loading at least 4 bytes per thread.  Even if your underlying data structures are byte-oriented, this can be accomplished with basic pointer casting (`char *` to `int *` for example) using appropriate pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Does it make difference if I load a 4 bytes data by each thread vs. 1 byte data from global memory? how much is the biggest amount of data that I can load from global memory by a thread? If I can load 32 data values in parallel can I load the biggest data value by each Thread? does it affect on memory access ?

Comment: Perhaps you should pose a new question.  The maximum amount of data that can be retrieved by a single thread in a single access cycle is covered in the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses), it is 16 bytes (e.g. `uint4` vector type, for example).  Since 32 threads are in a warp, loading 4 bytes per thread will yield a 128 byte load, which will fully utilize (100% efficiency) a global load request.  There is no additional benefit, compared to that, by increasing the per-thread load beyond 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the paradigm is use a for loop over the block. Remember, shared memory is only shared between blocks, so if your shared memory is larger than the number of blocks you'll need to have a fancy loop.

At the beginning of the kernel, have something like this.

```
//loadbuff is a T*, T is whatever type you want
//sharedmemsize is some (compile time) constant
__shared__ T sharedmem[sharedmemsize]; 
int index = threadidx.x;
int blocksize = blockDim.x;

for (int i = index; i < sharedmemsize; i+=blocksize)
{
   sharedmem[i]=loadbuff[i];
}
__syncthreads();
```